# Format number when click outside input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hello i have many input and i want to format number when i click outside to the input.

Here my Html :

```html
<div class="mdc-text-field col-5 px-0 InputForcage mr-2" data-id="@IdValueLine" style="@(IsForcage == "True" ? "" : "display:none")">
@Html.TextBox("InputToForce", IsForcage == "True" ? ValForce : "0", new { @class = "mdc-text-field__input number InputForcage", @style = "text-align:right;font-size:14px;", data_id = IdValueLine })
<label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field" style="left:unset">Forcage</label>
<div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>
```

Here my js :

```js
$("input[type=text].InputForcage, input[type=number].InputForcage").each(function () {
    $(this).blur(function () {
        OnNumBlur(this);
    });
});
```

Here my problem that when i click outside to input after writting a number and i have breakpoint on my function the breakpoint dosn't working and my file js is loaded in the html so i have a problem in the selector of my function or another think ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q930tsyx/ probably you are loading your js before html

Comment: yes this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use the `each()` function from jquery. You need to use `$(this)` instead of simple `this`

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" /> 
  <input type="text" />
</div>

$("input").each(function () {
  $(this).blur(() => {
    console.log($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the OnBlur event?

```
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
```